# webview working only for one time it remember page

Tags: android

My name is amit
I need fix two little issues in my app.
1.The webview app not always sync from the webpage, just once and then it remember the page, I make changes they not showing in the app.
2.Can i make my app only portrait ?

---

### MainActicity

```
package com.example.amit.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://149.78.164.142");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        this.setContentView(mWebView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

---

### activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.amit.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mwebView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.amit.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: sorry i am unable to understand problem. Will u pl explain what a prob u r facing?

Answer (score 0):

set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to your `<activity>` tag to make your app layout portrait..